# Remix plugin for VS Code reads 404

Tags: remix, vscode

On the official Remix website [Remix - Ethereum IDE & community](https://remix-project.org/) the link to Ethereum Remix VS Code Extension reads 404. How could one find the official extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link, I also used it, a pretty good extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maxdavidwow.remix-light